# Querying multiple columns with android Search Action

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

I am a months years Old in the android world, I would really appreciate your help.

I am trying to use the Android Search suggestions, while being able to query two tables from my database. E.g TableName = Hymn. I want to search from HymnNumber &
Category Columns.

My Problem: 
Solution One - The Solution below works, but my "Search Suggestions" aren't displayed. And also I get an error when I add my selectionArgs (FYI it works fine without the selectionArgs).

```
String selection1 =
            Hymn_Number + " LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR "
            + Category + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'" ;
```

Here's the error I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

Solution Two: The code below works fine also (Search Suggestions is displayed), but it doesn't query the "Second Column". (FYI I get no errors when I add my selectionArgs )

```
        String selection2 = Hymn_Number + " LIKE ? " + " OR " + Category + " LIKE ? ";
```

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
/** Returns Hymns  */
public Cursor getHymns(String query, String[] selectionArgs){

    if(selectionArgs!=null){
        selectionArgs[0] = "%"+selectionArgs[0] + "%";
    }

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(mAliasMap);

    queryBuilder.setTables(hymnDao.getTablename());


    String Hymn_Number = HymnDao.Properties.HymnNumber.columnName;
    String Category = HymnDao.Properties.Category.columnName;


    //Working Code
    String selection1 =
            Hymn_Number + " LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR "
            + Category + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'" ;

    String selection2 = Hymn_Number + " LIKE ? " + " OR " + Category + " LIKE ? ";


    String[] projectionIn = {"_ID",
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};


    Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(database,
            projectionIn,
            selection2,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            Category + " asc ","10"
    );
    return c;

}
```